# SPARQL query on a specific RDF format

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am trying to query a specific RDF file.  I  need this solution for my work.

The file I have to work with is:
https://github.com/iliriani/Test/blob/main/Notebook.rdf

I am trying to get somehow all the attributes ( <attribute'>...<'name> ) of a given class( <class'>...<name'> ) within this model. But cannot find the right query!

For instance, I want to get all attributes of class "Teacher", it should return me:

- id
- Emri
- Mbiemri
- Lendet
- Evaluations
- User

Hope for your support.

Comment: it's the same question as on the Apache Jena mailing list ...

Comment: `prefix : <http://acandonorway.github.com/XmlToRdf/ontology.ttl#>
base <http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/>
select ?o {


?x <Name> "Teacher" ;
 :hasChild/:hasChild/<Name> ?o . 
} `